# Where to find a someone for QGIS custom programming

Tags: qgis, gps, tracking, nmea

I need some custom programming done in QGIS to solve some issues I raised in this question ([Separate NMEA String in QGIS for position tracking](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/411005/separate-nmea-string-in-qgis-for-position-tracking)), as well as some other associated work

Where is an appropriate place to source someone to do this? Is there a forum for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the QGIS website there is a page on [Commercial support](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/commercial_support.html) that state :

> Are you looking for a developer to add features you need or fix bugs
> you encounter? Here is an alphabetical list, divided in categories, of
> support contractors

This could be a good first place to look at

Comment: I would stick to this list and maybe have a look which of these companies (I'm not affiliated to any) is involved in QGIS development (especially the functions you need). They know the architecture of QGIS and it is also fair to reward those who as part of the commubity make QGIS run. We all profit from their work.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably look towards The Open Source Geospatial Foundation (osgeo.org) and specifically in the UK, the UK chapter: https://uk.osgeo.org/

I thought the UK OSGeo web site had a list of consultants, but that might have got out of date and been removed. But the OSGeo mailing list would be a good place to ask.